# Problem with Wifi Dongle

Tags: wifi

I purchased my [Raspberry Pi which came with a USB dongle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00G1PNG54) but when I connected it to my RPi, I went to my Wi-Fi config and entered my password and it didn't do anything yet it said it connected to my network. So I decided to use it on my desktop computer on Ubuntu to see if it worked, and it did. So I went back to my RPi and plugged it into my RPi, but now it came to a stop with these last two lines

```
Starting NTP server: ntpd.
Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server : sshd
```

after this it doesn't do anything, so I have to restart it without the Wi-Fi dongle and it works normally.

Can anyone tell me why this happened or how can I fix this? Otherwise, I won't be able to use the internet on my Raspberry Pi ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the USB port is faulty in some way. Try switching ports or trying out USB hubs.

Another problem could be having a wireless keyboard: the two adapters could be working on similar frequencies and the keyboard could be causing the dropout. Again, use a USB hub to get the two as far away from each other as possible.

For connecting to the internet, I found a strange phenomenon was that, to connect using the Wifi config tool in the GUI, you needed to have a browser installed.

Failing that, a trusty Ethernet cable will ensure internet connectivity.

Comment: i guess its time to use the ethernet cable, too bad i only have one....